# How to open an existing GitHub project with Xcode?

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am new to [xcode](/questions/tagged/xcode) and I want to learn iphone development.

I found one demo project on [github](https://github.com/sschroed/git-phone), I want to know how to open this existing project?

Comment: Are you asking "how to do I click on the .xcodeproj file to open a project" or how to get the code from GitHub?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

- Download the project via git / or zip
- Open folder
- Double click on .xcodeproj file
- if on the top left, you see a something like "Base sdk missing"

  - Double click on the first item in the three
  - Go to tag build

    - Select a sdk for the **Base SDK**
  - Close the opened popup
  - Click on build an run
  - If you have error, you should see a red icon on the right bottom

Comment: thanks! could you please tell how to open project directly with Xcode like netbeans

Comment: On the first modal view, click on "Open other" the go select your project else you can clic "File > Open" from the top menu.

Answer (score 9):

Note: since June 2016, you can open your demo GitHub project in Xcode directly from the GitHub site!

But you will need the [latest Xcode 9](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/), announced [at the 2017 WWDC](https://www.theverge.com/2017/6/5/15722994/apple-wwdc-2017-news-highlights-recap)

See "**[Clone in Xcode](https://github.com/blog/2375-clone-in-xcode)**"

> It's easy to explore code in your browser when you visit a GitHub repository, but you often want to pull that code directly into the appropriate editor and try it out.
>   For example, if the repository contains an `.xcodeproj` or `.xcworkspace` file, you might want to open that code in Xcode.
>
> This is possible starting today with the new "**Open in Xcode**" button.

[image: https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/19977/26796930/158f0a5c-49e0-11e7-8c26-eb666b7f666c.gif]

That will trigger the `git clone` for you.

**Note**: as illustrated in "[Unable to see “Open in Xcode” button on GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50970245/6309)", you also have to be logged in to GitHub in Xcode as well.

> In Xcode, navigate to `Preferences.../Accounts`, select `GitHub` and enter your login credentials.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however I'm having the following issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50969013/unable-to-see-open-in-xcode-at-github. Any idea? :)

Comment: @AhmadF I come after the battle, but I see you got an answer. I included your question in my own answer above for more visibility.

Answer (score 0):

Using `xed ./ios` in the terminal of the root of the app worked for me.