# Unable to see "Open in Xcode" button on GitHub

Tags: xcode, git, github, version-control

As mentioned in the [GitHub and the New Source Control Workflows in Xcode 9](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/405/?time=204) Apple video session, we are able to clone the project directly from Xcode, as shown at [Clone in Xcode](https://blog.github.com/2017-06-05-clone-in-xcode/).

However, for some reason I can't see it:

[image: "Open in Xcode" button not visible on GitHub]

Please note that:

- I am using Safari.
- I've already logged in to GitHub.
- The installed version of Xcode is 9.3.

Since I have installed Xcode 9.x, I would assume that it should be automatically appear when clicking the "clone or download" button. Should I do extra work to be able to see it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**UPDATE:** in Xcode 12, this works even without logging in.

---

**Original answer:**

You have to be logged in to GitHub in Xcode as well.

In Xcode, navigate to **Preferences.../Accounts**, click on the **+** button in the lower left corner, select GitHub and enter your login credentials. After that, refresh the GitHub page and you should see the button.

[image: added GitHub account in Xcode]

[image: "Open in Xcode" button on GitHub]

Fun fact: you don't even have to use Safari, the button is available in other browsers as well (such as Chrome).

Comment: I forgot about this one. Thanks ;)

Comment: I cannot seem to get it to work. I log in with my xcode and refresh github but it does not give me the option. Even when I clone the project, I cannot open it on xcode even though its now in my dev folder.

Comment: Apparently, the project has to have it's `.xcodeproj` located in the root folder for this to work.

Comment: @Mojo66 I can confirm that this is the case for me as well. It's such as shame because Swift Packages usually don't have a  `.xcodeproj`.